# Protocols & Delegate when using ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have a UIViewController (root) with a ContainerView that loads a nib programatically:

```
UIView *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardView" 
    owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

I have a class file (.h and .m) hooked to this .xib file (UIView).
My .xib file (UIView) has a button and an action.

When this action is invoked and executed I removeFromParent my .xib file.

How can my ViewController.m (root) handle the exact time I removeFromParent my nib file?

I tried to use Protocol & Delegate but it failed.
I tried to set delegate=self on prepareForSegue Method but was unsuccessful.

My question is:
My UIViewController (root) invokes my keyboard (.xib) programatically.
All action in my keyboard are handled by the class hooked to the .xib.
After action’s job is done I removeFromParent the .nib file (I simulate a dismiss).

How can methods in ViewController.m (root) know that I dismissed my .xib file?

Comment: Post the code for your delegate method as well.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is KeyboardView a view, or a view controller? It looks to me like it's a view that you are adding as a subview. You say "When this action is invoked I removeFromParent..." does that mean that in the button action, you remove the view from it's parent view? is this view a custom subclass of UIView? It seems to me that in the IBAction for your view's button you should be able to send a message to the view controller that owns the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are doing here, but I think I understand your question.

In your interface, declare a weak property for the keyboard view.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *keyboardView;
```

Then when you load the keyboard

```
UIView *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardView" 
    owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
self.keyboardView = containerView;
```

Now you can test `self.keyboardView != nil` to know if the keyboard is loaded.

This works because `keyboardView` is weak so when it's removed from it's parent view the property will be set to `nil`.

---

NOTE: No protocol or delegate is needed.

Comment: Jeffery, my main issue is: After data entry is captured in my keyboard I need to return to root view controller passing data that was typed. So I need to dismiss my keyboard and let a specific method in root view controller know that the data gathered is ready to be processed (after user tap RETURN keypad in keyboard).

Comment: You should be using a `UITextField` and setting `textField.inputView` to be your keyboard view.